# Polygon which is drawn only with 2 points is not saving in ArcGIS Online service

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, polygon-creation

I have a polygon layer in ArcGIS Online,

When I draw a polygon by taking P1 as starting point and double click on the P2 so polygon draw end event will come from draw tool.

The below is the JSON format which I used to addFreature.

```
[
{
  "attributes" : {
    "attr1":"10008201",
    "attr2":"9",
    "attr3":"PMS"
  },
  "geometry" : {
    "type":"polygon",
    "rings":[[[8487016.789333614,1464112.0521501263],[8668631.168539183,1622489.5747570037],[8668631.168539183,1622489.5747570037],[8487016.789333614,1464112.0521501263]]],
    "_ring":0,
    "spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}

  }
}
```

]

The addFeature service says sucess. But the geometry of that feature is not saved in the ArcGIS Online layer.

So, I am thinking the polygon geometry is invalid so its not saving. 
But how to validate it from JavaScript API

Comment: The minimum number of points in a polygon is THREE.  The minimum number of vertices in a ring is FOUR (first verrtex == last vertex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the method you're looking for is [`geometryEngine.simplify()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengine-amd.html#simplify)

From the *API reference*:

> Performs the simplify operation on the geometry which alters the given geometries to make their definitions topologically legal with respect to their geometry type.